# How to use multiple arguments in \lstnewenvironment

Tags: listings

How can I have more than one optional argument to be passed to `\lstnewenvironment`?

I only need a fixed number of options and all will be present.

I want to pass the `frame` type and `font size` as arguments to my custom `lstlisting`.

**Update**

My current definition. I am currently passing the `font size`. I need `frame` type also (like `single`, `leftline` etc.)

```
\lstnewenvironment{pyout}[1][\tiny]{
    \lstset{ %
            basicstyle=\ttfamily#1\setstretch{1},
            showstringspaces=false,
            upquote=true,
            aboveskip=0pt,
            belowskip=2pt,
            breaklines=true,
            frame=leftline,
    }
}{}
```

Comment: You can easily use `[2]` or `[3]` or …. Keep in mind that if you specify the second optional argument (here: `\tiny`) the first argument of the `pyout` environment will be optional, but only the first one. You can’t specify more than one optional argument with `\lstnewenvironment`. I’d advise you to use the key-value system.

Comment: Two optional arguments are a nuisance, because the second can be specified only if the first is present.

Comment: @egreg I understand, I will either give all arguments or none. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I didn't get `[2]`, `[3]`. Is that the `[1]` in current definition? I don't know what the `number` means.

Comment: Why not `\lstnewenvironment{pyout}[1][,]{\lstset{..,#1}}{}` which would allow you to use `\begin{pyout}[..,frame=leftline,..]`...`\end{pyout}`? If need be, you can define your own shorter versions of the keys.

Comment: @Werner Genius man... works great... can you put it as an answer...

Comment: @ATOzTOA: That's offered by @egreg's solution. He's just added a `fontsize` key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a new `fontsize` key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,setspace,textcomp}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifATOfontsize
\lst@Key{fontsize}{\tiny}{\def\ATOfontsize{#1}\global\ATOfontsizetrue}
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{pyout}[1][]{%
  \global\ATOfontsizefalse
  \lstset{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny\setstretch{1},
    showstringspaces=false,
    upquote=true,
    aboveskip=0pt,
    belowskip=2pt,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=leftline,
    #1,
    }
  \ifATOfontsize
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\ATOfontsize\setstretch{1}}
  \fi
  }{}

\begin{document}
\begin{pyout}[fontsize=\normalsize]
abc
\end{pyout}
\begin{pyout}[frame=single]
abc
\end{pyout}
\begin{pyout}[fontsize=\normalsize,frame=single]
abc
\end{pyout}
\end{document}
```

If the key is specified, a second `\lstset` command will be executed, for setting the font size.

In the following picture I've only reduced the text width.

[image]