# Adding a default argument to a custom command

Tags: macros, listings

I'm using the listings package to show some Python code, but I can't seem to provide an optional argument that is the font size used by the algorithm. Y would like the algorithm to be printed in normal size, but if I pass a parameter to the `python` environment, to use the new font size instead.
I've seen many posts about how the `\newcommand` works, but I can't seem to make it work (I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812214/latex-optional-arguments) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58628/optional-argument-for-newcommand) for example
). The code I started with is this one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{language=Python,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
  showstringspaces=false,
  emph={ClassName},          % Custom highlighting
  morekeywords={>, >=, <, <=, ==, !=, __init__, __new__, __lt__, __eq__, __ne__, __le__, __ge__, __gt__, __repr__, __str__, __del__, __format__, __hash__, __bool__}
}}
% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][mathescape]
{
\pythonstyle
\lstset{#1}
}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
def hi(s):
    print("how are you?")
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

Comment: listings allows you to define your own style (\lstdefinestyle{name}{code}`, so make one, say, `pythonstyle` and then use `\lstset{style=phytonstyle,#1}`,

Comment: Didn't really understand your question. Are you searching for `\begin{python}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\Huge]`?

Comment: You question is unclear. You are speaking of font sizes, but use mathescape as example. Beside this `\begin{python}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny]` works fine.

Comment: It's in the code, I would like to replace `\normalsize` by a user parameter if it's given or else use the normal size. I tried what @daleif suggested with lo luck.

Comment: `\normalsize` is not an option, and listings does not know what do do with `\begin{python}[\normalsize]` all options in listings are key=value bases, and thus you need to use that. Sadly you cannot spit `basicstyle` into separate font and size part

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100720/89417

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do this, because the solution of the question already supports using, e.g., `\begin{python}[\basicstyle=\ttfamily\Huge]`, nevertheless:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\pythonstyle[1][\normalsize]{\lstset{language=Python,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily#1,
  showstringspaces=false,
  emph={ClassName},          % Custom highlighting
  morekeywords={>, >=, <, <=, ==, !=, __init__, __new__, __lt__, __eq__, __ne__, __le__, __ge__, __gt__, __repr__, __str__, __del__, __format__, __hash__, __bool__}
}}
% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][\normalsize]
{
\pythonstyle[#1]
}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
def hi(s):
    print("how are you?")
\end{python}

\begin{python}[\Huge]
def hi(s):
    print("how are you?")
\end{python}


\end{document}
```